# API Design: Multiple $_REQUEST's vs single $_REQUEST encoded in json

Tags: php, api, json

I'm building an API, and I'm at a crossroads as how to implement it. I plan on using json, since they can represent objects/arrays so easily in php and javascript.

I have two ways to implement it pretty much:

1) Include the method call into the json

```
$input = $_REQUEST['i'];
$i_obj = json_decode($input);
api_handle($i_obj);
```

2) Push the method call (and perhaps other variables, such as the session) in parallel, and just pull the data via $_REQUEST.

```
$method = $_REQUEST['m'];
$argv = json_decode($_REQUEST['argv']);
api_handle($method,$argv);
```

I can see that in the second case, there may be less for the json_decode to debug, but from a user friendly point of view, an ajax/js coder could just build the object and send it json_encoded via input "i".

My question in the end is, are either of these good ways to implement this, or is there perhaps an even better way? Please keep in mind, this is a simple example, and does not represent the rest of the project's scope for this API.

Comment: Unless your API is indeterminate where its input is coming from (which it should be) don't use `$_REQUEST`. Values from `$_COOKIE` are stored there as well.

Comment: I understand that using the $_COOKIE could result in odd issues when using multiple sites on the same domain, but it is importiant to mention that, thank you. Other than that, what the disadvantage of not knowing where the data is coming from? Or are you thinking of specific keys/hashes/encryptions to represent different sources? It's too easy to spoof these kind if things.

Comment: (By these things, I mean relying on referers or such)

Comment: There's an order of precedence which isn't fixed but defaults to `GPC`. If your API gets a `POST` request to the URL `...?foo=bar` and `$_POST` contains a `foo=zoid`, it might cause undefined behavior.

Comment: When we're talking about undefined behavior, are we talking about logging some kind of error, or just one of the values (`[zoid|bar]`) being assigned to the variable `foo`? Also, I am still interested in the indeterimate part of your comment.

Comment: I just ran a test on my LAMP stack, and I'm getting a post over a get. http://pastebin.com/vQsuwcf1. Strike that, just found http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order in google.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case it's better idea to couple all method call data into one object rather then getting it from `$_REQUEST` key by key since `$_REQUEST` contains other unrelated data as well at the same level.
Method name and its arguments are tied together and must be transferred as single packet. Maybe some day you'll deside to add ability to call i.e. class static methods. It will be much harder to add one more key to `$_REQUEST` and its processing then add one more field to object since object is much more encapsulated thing and that will narrow area affected by changes in your code.
And of course you can name object fields by a whim withot thinking if this key is already taken in `$_REQUEST` by another script.